# Read all rows inside a .net core view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am currently experimenting with .NET core by creating a fictional Bookstore.

In the database I have 3 tables:
1. Books - all the books 
2. Authors - all the authors
3. BookAuthors - intermediary (many-to-many relationship) b/n Books and Authors

I want to be able to read all current Authors and show them to the user when she wants to add a new Book (so if a given author exists she could select it).

I tried something like this in my BookController:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add()
    {
        var book = await _appDbContext.Books
        .Include(b => b.BookAuthors)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Author)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync()

        return View(book);
    }
```

However, if I try that I get this exception thrown: 
[image]

If I try something like:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Add()
    {
        var book = await _appDbContext.Books
        .Include(b => b.BookAuthors)
            .ThenInclude(a => a.Author)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BookId == 2);

        return View(book);
    }
```

it works, but it only returns one author (of course :))

[image]

If someone could help me a bit I would really appreciate it. 
Thank you!

Comment: would be helpful if you post your Razor View too

Answer (score 1):

In your Razor view you are expecting a **single** book.

But from the controller your are passing a **list** of books.

That is what the exception tells you.

If you want to process the list of books in your Razor view you need to change your model to `List<MyBookstore.Models.Book>` and iterate the result

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I've already tried that. I found a solution that I would post in my next comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the solution I've used ViewComponent that lists all Authors in the database.

1. Created new folder in my project called *ViewComponents*
2. Inside it I've created an **AuthorsListViewComponent.cs**

   ```
   public class AuthorsListViewComponent : ViewComponent
   {
     private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;

   public AuthorsListViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext appDbContext)
   {
       _appDbContext = appDbContext;
   }

   public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
   {
       var authorsList = await GetItemsAsync();
       return View(authorsList);
   }

   private Task<List<Author>> GetItemsAsync()
   {
       return _appDbContext.Authors.ToListAsync();
   }
   ```

   }
3. Inside *Views/Shared/Components/AuthorsList* I've created the view
   @model IEnumerable

```html
@model IEnumerable<Author>

<h2>Authors List</h2>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select Author(hold ctrl / shift for multiple selection):</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" multiple>
        @foreach (var author in Model)
        {
            <option>@author.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

4. Then I simply used the ViewComponent inside my **Add.cshtml**

```html
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("AuthorsList")
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```